# Webapp: When user submits a second request before the 1st one is "finished" the browser shows the output of the first req. why?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsp, servlets, browser

### Summary

In our web application when the user clicks "faster" than the page loads, apparently the browser shows the first request to the user (according to some error messages we get). I would have expected that to be the second request.

### More background information

We have a Struts1 web application. In the user session we put the current context of the user interaction.

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("context", <something>);
```

For instance, the app shows a list of master records, and the context holds information about the user. When the user clicks on a master record, we save the the information  about that record in the user session object. In the JSPs we often would assign the context object to a local variable. This needs casting to the specific type (e.g. `MasterRecordDTO` or `UserDTO`):

```
<% MasterRecordDTO dto = (MasterRecordDTO) request.getSession().getAttribute("context"); %>
```

The user can then drill down into details views of that master record. We have a breadcrumbs showing sth like `list > master > detail`. These are links so the user can navigate using breadcrumbs.

Now when in that situation the user clicks first on "master" and quickly enough on "list" he gets an ClassCastException saying

```
"UserDTO cannot be cast to MasterRecordDTO"
```

in the MasterRecord-JSP, which means that when the MasterRecord-JSP assigns the `dto` variable in the first request, the second request has already set the `context` session attribute to a `UserDTO` object.

### Question

I would have expected that the browser would "abandon" the first request and shows the result of the second request to the user (the list of master records in this example). Can anybody explain this to me?

### Update

The breadcrumb links are in another HTML Frame. We have this issue with Internet Explorer 7. I tried it with Firefox 11 but apparently it doesn't even submit the second click.

Comment: I guess it's a general concurrent programming situation. browser send 2 request *simultaneously*. (1) request/thread 1 set `context` to `MasterRecordDTO` (2) request/thread 2 changed to `UserDTO` (3) request/thread 1 continue running, and `ClassCastException` occured. The behaviour of browser is not controled by your application, it just show the result of response 1. try to use request scope to store such context.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a general concurrent programming situation.

The browser send 2 request *simultaneously* to server, the server use 2 threads to handle 2 request.

1. request/thread 1 set session attribute `context` to `MasterRecordDTO`
2. request/thread 2 then changed it to `UserDTO` (*Here's the source of the problem*)
3. request/thread 1 continue running, it will cause `ClassCastException` occured.
4. request/thread 2 continue running, it will generate a successful response to client. (but the browser does not show it)

The behaviour of browser is not controled by your application, it just show the result of response 1 (sometimes may be response 2, it's also a concurrent situation, because most current browsers are multi-threading designed).

Try to **use request scope** to store such `context` information to get an expected result.

Comment: LuiYan, thanks for taking time to answer my question. I am fully aware of the concurrent programming situation. It's just that I would have expected that the browser shows the result of the second, later click. The code for the first click would be executed anyway but the ClassCastException wouldn't be visible for the user.

Comment: I updated the question with a hint to IE7 as I could not reproduce the behaviour with FF 11.